# Why doesn't conservativeResize work with Ref variable in a function?

Tags: c++, eigen3

I am making a function that can extend the given Matrix which is MatrixXd type. I was trying to use conservativeResize to achieve that, but when i use Ref in the function statement, conservativeResize doesn't work with with the Ref object, but resize do. I am wondering why this problem happens. Thanks in advance.

I tried to use MatrixXd &var directly in function statement, and it does work, but I don't know why Ref doesn't.

````cpp
void mat_extend(Ref<MatrixXd> mat)
{
    int len = mat.rows();
    mat.conservativeResize(len+2,NoChange);
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

In your case `mat.resize(len+2,NoChange)`, won't work either. This should assert, unless you disabled assertions, in which case it will do nothing.

`Ref` does not allow resizing, since it does not "own" the memory it points to -- e.g., it could point to a `block` of another matrix, or to a `Map` of some externally allocated memory.

The reason that calling `resize` is allowed, is that in some generic code (including inside Eigen itself), matrices are first resized and then values are assigned. Guarding that by some `isResizeable` logic everywhere would be a mess.